# xml string is enclosed with b'<xml_string>' while generating from dictionary using dicttoxml module

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I am using [dicttoxml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dicttoxml) module for converting dictionary into xml.

**Code:**

```
cfg_dict = { 'mobile' :
                { 'checkBox_OS' :
                  { 'status' : 'None', 
                    'radioButton_Andriod' :
                      { 'status' : 'None',
                        'comboBox_Andriod_Brands' : 'LG'},
                    'radioButton_Windows' :
                      { 'status' : 'None',
                        'comboBox_Windows_Brands' : 'Nokia'},
                    'radioButton_Others' :
                      { 'status' : 'None',
                        'comboBox_Others_Brands' : 'Apple'}},
                  'checkBox_Screen_size' :
                    { 'status' : 'None',
                      'doubleSpinBox_Screen_size' : '5.0' }}
              }        

from dicttoxml import dicttoxml
xml = dicttoxml(self.cfg_dict)
print (xml)
```

**Output:**

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><root><mobile type="dict"><checkBox_OS type="dict"><radioButton_Andriod type="dict"><status type="bool">false</status><comboBox_Andriod_Brands type="str">Sony</comboBox_Andriod_Brands></radioButton_Andriod><radioButton_Windows type="dict"><status type="bool">false</status><comboBox_Windows_Brands type="str">HTC</comboBox_Windows_Brands></radioButton_Windows><status type="bool">false</status><radioButton_Others type="dict"><status type="bool">false</status><comboBox_Others_Brands type="str">Apple</comboBox_Others_Brands></radioButton_Others></checkBox_OS><checkBox_Screen_size type="dict"><doubleSpinBox_Screen_size type="float">5.0</doubleSpinBox_Screen_size><status type="bool">false</status></checkBox_Screen_size></mobile></root>'
```

I do not know why it is enclosed with b' '. How to generate xml string without this b''?

Browser is also giving error msg when opening xml file with this content.

Comment: Can you share us the content of "self.cfg_dict"

Comment: @TanveerAlam : Added the dict content

Comment: An interesting finding, type of return is of class 'bytes'

Comment: Here is my workaround for now `xml = str(xml)[2:-1]` to strip off the b' ' enclosure.

Comment: You can you use xml pretty to get it in proper xml format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the normal represenation of a String that is not Unicode in Python 3. Try this in the Python shell:

```
>>> type("foo")
<class 'str'>
>>> type(b"foo")
<class 'bytes'>
>>> type("Rübe")
<class 'str'>
>>> type(b"Rübe")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters.
```

So everything is OK. You don't have a problem.

See also [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) vs [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview).

**Edit:**

See how encoding and decoding works.

```
>>> s = "Rübe"
>>> e = s.encode("UTF-8")
>>> print(e)
b'R\xc3\xbcbe'
>>> type(e)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> d = e.decode("UTF-8")
>>> d
'Rübe'
```

So just use `my_byte_string.decode(my_encoding)`  where `my_encoding` is probably `"UTF-8"`.

Comment: Thanks!!, Is there a method to convert into normal string without b''?

Answer (score 5):

Library author here.

It appears you're using Python 3. Python 3 stores strings in binary format unless you specify an encoding.

Continuing with your example code, to convert `xml` from a string of bytes to a string of characters, use the `decode` method:

```
>>> xml_string = xml.decode('utf-8')
>>> print(xml_string)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><root><mobile type="dict"><checkBox_OS type="dict"><radioButton_Windows type="dict"><status type="str">None</status><comboBox_Windows_Brands type="str">Nokia</comboBox_Windows_Brands></radioButton_Windows><radioButton_Others type="dict"><comboBox_Others_Brands type="str">Apple</comboBox_Others_Brands><status type="str">None</status></radioButton_Others><status type="str">None</status><radioButton_Andriod type="dict"><comboBox_Andriod_Brands type="str">LG</comboBox_Andriod_Brands><status type="str">None</status></radioButton_Andriod></checkBox_OS><checkBox_Screen_size type="dict"><status type="str">None</status><doubleSpinBox_Screen_size type="str">5.0</doubleSpinBox_Screen_size></checkBox_Screen_size></mobile></root>
```

Cheers!